# Scrapy is filtering unique urls as duplicate urls

Tags: python, scrapy

The urls:

1. http://www.extrastores.com/en-sa/products/mobiles/smartphones-99500240157?page=1
2. http://www.extrastores.com/en-sa/products/mobiles/smartphones-99500240157?page=2 are unique but scrapy is filtering these urls as duplicates and not scraping them.[image]

I am using CrawlSpider with these rules:

```
rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css=('.resultspagenum'))),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('\/mobiles\/smartphones\/[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*',), ), callback='parse_product'),
)`
```

I do not understand this behavior, can somebody explain please? The same code was working last week.
Using Scrapy version 1.3.0

Comment: are you sure they weren't already visited?

Comment: Yes, nothing is getting scrapped from the whole website. All the links are getting filtered.

Comment: may be link scraped, but nothing data on page?

Comment: I could download/scrape data of an individual link in a shell, the mentioned links work fine in a scrapy shell.

Comment: I suggest that you share your crawl logs and perhaps your spider as well. The default fingerprint function yield different fingerprints for your 2 sample URLs. So scrapy should not be filtering all `page=<digit>` as the same, it's filtering them because they were already fetched. Can't say more without logs with `LOG_LEVEL='DEBUG'` or code or both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the suggestion of  @paul trmbrth I rechecked the code and website that is getting scraped. Scrapy is downloading the links and filtering the links because they were downloaded before. The issue was the link attribute in 'a' tag of html was changed from a static link to some javascript function:

```
<a href='javascript:gtm.traceProductClick("/en-sa/mobiles/smartphones/samsung-galaxy-s7-32gb-dual-sim-lte-gold-188024">
```

Correspondingly I changed my spider code as:

```
    def _process_value(value):
    m = re.search('javascript:gtm.traceProductClick\("(.*?)"', value)
    if m:
        return m.group(1)


rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css=('.resultspagenum'))),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(
        allow=('\/mobiles\/smartphones\/[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*',),
        process_value=_process_value
    ), callback='parse_product'),
)
```

This was not he issue of scrapy filtering non-unique urls but it was about the extracting the link from 'href' attribute from 'a' tag because that link was changed recently and my code was broken. 
Thanks again @paul trmbrth